# Landau Notation arithmetic

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a thread or guide how to the small $\mathcal{O}$ Landau symbol arithmetic? I would like to know how to calculate for example why $(1-\alpha h + \mathcal{O}(h))^n = 1-n\alpha h+\mathcal{O}(h)$ and others and do not really understand how to get there.

We said that $\mathcal{O}$ is any function for which $\lim_{h\downarrow0} \frac{\mathcal{O}(h)}{h}=0$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Small $\mathcal O$ should be $o$ since it's small.

Comment: You can look at §8.1 in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or, if you read French, §1 in [Comparaison asymptotique](https://fr.wikipedia.org).